# Bootstrap responsive columns conflict

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div which I've provided **col-xl-21 col-lg-20 col-md-20 offset-sm-0 offset-lg-2 offset-xl-2 offset-md-3** classes. Now the problem is xl keeps over-riding md styles. Is there something missing in my code?

```
 <div className="col-xl-21 col-lg-20 col-md-20 offset-sm-0 offset-lg-2 offset-xl-2 offset-md-3">{renderTable()}</div>
```

On medium desktop screens, it should use `md` styles. In same way, use `lg` for large-screens and `xl` for extra-large screens.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum `col-**-**` allowed in bootstrap is `col-**-12`. Below are the break-points.
Beyond `col-**-12` doesn't make any sense

```
.col-xs- <768px Extra small
.col-sm- >=768px Small
.col-md- >=992px Medium
.col-lg- >=1200px Large
```

[Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp)